# Can we write iphone program in C?

Tags: c, ios, xcode

I learned that Xcode can compile c code, that means can we write whole program in c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Objective C is a strict superset of C. This means that any C code is valid also in Objective C. But most of framework APIs are in Objective C, if you need to call these, you will have to include Objective C code as well. However standard C libraries are supported and even for 2D graphics there are Cocoa classes in C.